# What GIT commands TFS executes

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to see what GIT commands TFS 2017 executes ?

For example when I do compare branches on TFS ,what GIT command does TFS executes.
Does it run `git diff branch_1..branch_2` or `git diff branch_1...branch_2`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for comparing Git branch:

Use `git diff` to compare the contents of two branches. You can compare any combination of local and remote branches. The output shows the deletions and additions between the two versions of the code.

```
git diff users/frank/feature origin/master
```

More details please refer this tutorial: *[Compare branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/history?view=vsts&tabs=command-line#compare-branches)*

There is no way to directly see what GIT commands TFS 2017 executes. However you could refer official doc in MSDN: [VSTS Git tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/gitworkflow?view=vsts) which include many operations and corresponding git command line. Just click the **Command Line** tab beside Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Since there are many uses of `GIT DIFF` I'm still at dark about which command TFS 2017 uses, i guess TFS 2017 Pull request uses `Git Diff master ... feature` to make the comparison, but unless we are certain then the answer is still NO

Comment: @NuwanDammika Sorry there is not any official Microsoft doc state this for now.  And either use  `git diff branch_1..branch_2` or `git diff branch_1  branch_2` it's synonymous . Based on my understanding and test, for pull request, it should use `git diff branch_1..branch_2`  instead of `git diff branch_1...branch_2`   More details please refer https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff